# How to print modulo of specific value using List comprehension ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list a,

```
a = ['python', 'django', 'python with django']
```

What i want to do is ,

**if number is divisible by 3 then print 'python'**

**if number is divisible by 5 then print 'django'**

**if number is divisible by 3 and 5 both then print 'python with django'**

This is my code

```
for n, i in enumerate(range(20)):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print n, a[0]
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print n, a[1]
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print n, a[2]
```

and **O/P is**

```
0 python
3 python
5 django
6 python
9 python
10 django
12 python
15 python
18 python
```

and i **need this Result**

```
0 python with django
3 python
5 django
6 python
9 python
10 django
12 python
15 python with django
18 python
```

Can i use **List Comprehension** or is there any pythonic way

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered, since that can be confusing for future readers, and it can make the answers look weird or wrong. If necessary, add new information to the end of your question, leaving the original info intact.

Answer (score 1):

Your way seems fine but you have your code a little bit incorrect. Here is the correct code:

```
for n, i in enumerate(range(20)):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print n, a[2]
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print n, a[0]
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print n, a[1]
```

You must have it check for if the number is divisible by 3 and 5 first. If you don't and it is divisible by 3 that meets the condition of the first `if` statement so it will not check any of the `elif` statements because `elif` is only checked if the previous `if` or `elif` statements were not met.  The same goes for if the number is divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will probably end up looking too convoluted in this case. Just move the last of your three conditions to the top. Otherwise, if a number is divisble by 3 and by 5, the check for being divisible by 3 alone will be successful first and your `elif` chain means the combined check will never be reached. And by the way, you need not enumerate the range you iterate over, just use `i` in place of `n`.

To make the code a little less verbose (but also a little less straight-forward) you could get away with one check less:

```
for i in range(20):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        if i % 5 == 0:
            print i, a[2]
        else:
            print i, a[0]
    elif i % 5 == 0 :
        print i, a[1]
```

Comment: I got condition but is there some way to check those easier

Comment: In the end, you need to make at least two decisions in order to distinguish 3 cases. I'll edit the answer since there's no way to format multi-line code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your FizzBuzz task.

```
a = ['python with django' if x%15 == 0 else ('python' if x%3 == 0 else 'django') for x in xrange(20)]
```